# filter array of objects based on separate object values by keys using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the array below:

```
[
 {
   "Name": "Test1",
   "powers": "Push",
   "color": "Yellow",
   "fortune": 100,
   "home": "Hoth",
   "transportation": "Star Destroyer"
 },
 {
  "Name": "Test2",
  "powers": "Lighning",
  "color": "Yellow",
  "fortune": 4004,
  "home": "Tatooine",
  "transportation": "Star Destroyer"
}
]
```

I want to separate a value below keys

---

1. Name
   Test1
   Test2
2. powers
   Push
   Lighning
3. color
   Yellow
   Yellow
4. fortune
   100
   4004
5. home
   Hoth
   Tatooine
6. transportation
   Star Destroyer
   Star Destroyer

Comment: what have you tried yet?

Comment: { dataqq.reduce((keys, obj) => (
    keys.concat(Object.keys(obj).filter(key => (
      keys.indexOf(key) === -1))
    )
  ), []).filter(ff => ff !== "Name").map((ff)=>{
      console.log(ff)
    })

i tried this but not working

Comment: I have added an answer, let me know if this is what you need.

Comment: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (139:16)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|     io.push(tableqdata);
|     const pp = dataqq.reduce((keys, obj) => keys.concat(Object.keys(obj).map(k => {
>       (keys[k] ??= []).push(obj[k]);
|     })), []);
|     console.log(pp);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `reduce` and group them based on the key:

```js
const arr = [ { "Name": "Test1", "powers": "Push", "color": "Yellow", "fortune": 100, "home": "Hoth", "transportation": "Star Destroyer" }, { "Name": "Test2", "powers": "Lighning", "color": "Yellow", "fortune": 4004, "home": "Tatooine", "transportation": "Star Destroyer"}];

const result = arr.reduce((a,o)=>{
    Object.keys(o).forEach(k=>{
        (a[k] ??= []).push(o[k])
    });
    return a;
},{});

console.log(result);
```